# XCode : How to use cmd + x to either cut the current line (if no text is selected) or cut the selected text

Tags: macos, xcode, development, mojave, ide

Pressing `cmd + x` without selecting text in other IDEs, cuts the complete line. Same goes for `cmd + c` which copies, instead of cutting. Otherwise, if some text is selected, only that region is cut.

How do I do this in XCode?

I added the following in the `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` to add cutting line and copying line functionality :

```
<key>My Custom Commands</key>
<dict>
    <key>Cut Current Line</key>
    <string>selectLine:, cut:</string>
    <key>Copy Current Line</key>
    <string>selectLine:, copy:</string>
</dict>
```

But obviously binding these to `cmd + x` (or c) doesn't allow cutting/copying selected region. I understand I can set it to some other keybinding. But, as a force of habit, `cmd + x` (or c) suits better.

Is there any way to do this? Maybe an extension?

[PS I asked the same question on StackOverflow, but realised, this is more apt place]

Comment: There's an extra `</dict>` at the end of the plist. You might want to remove that so that people don't accidentally mess up the plist file if they copy the above text.

Answer (score 9):

That is correct. (Xcode 10)

1. Add the entry for cut line and copy line in the `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist` file
2. Save the `IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist`
3. Restart Xcode
4. Set a key for the new command through xcode > preferences > key bindings > My Custom Commands
5. Resolve conflicts

---

Example: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Cut and Copy</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Cut Current Line</key>
        <string>selectLine:, cut:</string>
        <key>Copy Current Line</key>
        <string>selectLine:, copy:</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Duplication</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Duplicate Current Line</key>
        <string>moveToBeginningOfLine:, deleteToEndOfLine:, yank:, insertNewline:, moveToBeginningOfLine:, yank:</string>
        <key>Duplicate Lines</key>
        <string>selectLine:, copy:, moveToEndOfLine:, insertNewline:, paste:, deleteBackward:</string>
        <key>Delete Line</key>
        <string>selectLine:, deleteBackward:</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Xcode keybinding (Cut and Copy):
[image]

Xcode conflict resolve (Cut and Copy):
[image]

Comment: I've didn't tried but I think it doesn't fit the need of either copy the line or the selected text. Am I wrong?

Comment: I see what you mean, that's correct, it does not take into consideration if text has been selected or not. If the information is not useful I can remove this post.

Comment: What I usually do is I add shift to cut/copy keys to cut/copy a line instead of the selected text eg.
| Copy selected text `cmd+c`
| Cut selected text `cmd+x`
| Copy line `shift+cmd+c`
| Cut line `shift+cmd+x`